# Subquery userId and productSKU

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query in-house defined userId and the hits.product.productSKU in [Google UA](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) However, when I ran the BigQuery SQL below, I got the `Scalar subquery produced more than one element` error. I wonder why...

```
with user_id_tbl as (
  select 
  fullVisitorId,
  (select value from unnest(hits.customDimensions) where index=5) as server_userId,
  (select productSKU from unnest(hits.product)) as productPrimary
  from `my_table`, unnest(hits) as hits
  where
    date between '2022-07-01' and '2023-06-30'
    and hits.eventInfo.eventCategory='offers'
)
select * from user_id_tbl where productPrimary is not null
```

Comment: This error happens because the unnest function can produce multiple rows for each row in the original table, and your subqueries are not limiting the results to just one row. To fix, you need to decide how you want to handle multiple results. One common approach is to use an aggregate function to combine the results, such as ARRAY_AGG to collect them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This approach uses the `ARRAY` and `SELECT AS STRUCT` constructs to first create an array of the desired values and then picks the first value from that array using `[safe_offset(0)]`. This ensures that even if there are multiple values, only the first one is selected, and the scalar subquery error is avoided.

```sql
with user_id_tbl as (
  select 
  fullVisitorId,
  (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) WHERE index=53))[safe_offset(0)].value as server_userId,
  (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT productSKU FROM UNNEST(hits.product)))[safe_offset(0)].productSKU as productPrimary
  from `my_table`, unnest(hits) as hits
  where
    date between '2022-07-01' and '2023-06-30'
    and hits.eventInfo.eventCategory='offers'
)
select * from user_id_tbl where productPrimary is not null
```

This approach uses the `ARRAY` and `SELECT AS STRUCT` constructs to first create an array of the desired values and then picks the first value from that array using `[safe_offset(0)]`. This ensures that even if there are multiple values, only the first one is selected, and the scalar subquery error is avoided.

Comment: Hi @Joaquin I tried the above query but still got `Scalar subquery produced more than one element` error... Is it because of the subquery of both server_userId and productPrimary?

Comment: likely due to both subqueries potentially returning multiple values. To resolve this, you can use the ARRAY_AGG function for both subqueries and then limit them to return the first value using [OFFSET(0)]. Would this work?

Comment: For the server_userId, I tried `(SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) WHERE index=53))[safe_offset(0)].value as server_userId` which worked well. However, I still had a difficult time querying **hits.product.productSKU** in the same query.

Comment: If (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) WHERE index=53))[safe_offset(0)].value as server_userId worked well for server_userId, then you can use a similar approach for hits.product.productSKU. Will update solution above.